# get() got an unexpected keyword argument 'title'

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-urls, django-class-based-views

i want to fetch a blog with a model field which is unique and but when i click on a perticular blog it throw me above mentioned error
here is my views

```
class Blogs(View):
    def get(self, request):
        blog_list = Blog.objects.order_by('-joined_date')
        return render(request, 'blogs.html',{'blog_list':blog_list})

class ReadBlogs(View):
def get(self, request, title):
    readblog = Blog.objects.filter(title=title)
    return render(request,'blogs_read.html', {'readblog':readblog})
```

my model

```
class Blog(models.Model):
    title  = models.CharField(max_length=48, blank=False)
    urltitle = models.SlugField(max_length=48, blank=False, unique=True)
    title_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='blog',blank=True, null=True)
    subone = models.CharField(max_length=80, blank=False)
    subone_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='blog',blank=True,null=True)
    onedes = models.TextField(blank=False)
```

my html for fetching  right blog

```
<div class="blogs">
            {% for blogs in blog_list %}
            <a class="products" href="{% url 'blogs:readblog' title=blogs.urltitle %}">
              <div class="blog col-4" style="width: 18rem; height:350px">
                  <img class="img" src="{{ blogs.title_image.url }}" alt="" height="250px" width="100%">
                  <div class="detail">
                  <h4 class="title text-center" style="color: #025; font-family:cursive;">{{blogs.title}}</h4>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </a>
            {% endfor %}
          </div>
```

my url.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('blogs/',Blogs.as_view(),name="Blogs"),
    path('<slug:title>/',ReadBlogs.as_view(),name="readblog")
]
```

as you can see mu urltitle is unique slug field so but when i clicked on a particular blog i got above mentioned error any idea what causing error

my template for showing realated field of that blog

```
<div class="col-11 card">
        <div class="blogs">
        {% for blog in readblog %}
          
          <h1 class="text-center" style="color: #025; font-family:cursive; margin-top:20px;">{{read.title}}</h1>
          
          {% endfor %}
        </div>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The URL parameter is named `title`, not <s>`url_title`</s>:

```
path('<slug:title>/',ReadBlogs.as_view(),name='readblog')
```

therefore the `.get(…)` method should work with `title` as parameter:

```
class ReadBlogs(View):
    
    #                title ↓
    def get(self, request, title):
        blog = Blog.objects.filter(title=title)
        return render(request,'blogs_read.html',{'blog':blog})
```

Here `blog` is a *collection* of zero, one, or more blogs. If you want to pass a *single* `Blog` object, you should fetch a single object, for example with `get_object_or_404`:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

class ReadBlogs(View):

    def get(self, request, title):
        blog = get_object_or_404(Blog, title=title)
        return render(request,'blogs_read.html',{'blog':blog})
```

It might also make more sense to work with a [**`DetailView`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#django.views.generic.detail.DetailView) to automatically render the item properly:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
from django.views.generic.detail import DetailView

class ReadBlogs(DetailView):
    model = Blog
    template_name = 'blogs_read.html'

    def get_object(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return get_object_or_404(Blog, title=self.kwargs['title'])
```

Comment: but still my template is not showing anyting when i tried to fetch the realated data of that blog

Comment: @Blackranger: the link should be `{% url 'blogs:readblog' title=blogs.title %}` so `blogs.title`, not `blogs.urltitle`, there is no `urltitle` (or at least not one that you show here).

Comment: @Blackranger: furthermore the last code fragment should be `{{blog.title}}`, not `{{ read.title }}`.

Comment: i want to use urltitle slug field in my url

Comment: which is also in models

Comment: @Blackranger: do the blog records have a (filled in) `urltitle` column? In that case, you should filter with `blog = Blog.objects.filter(urltitle=title)` in the view.

Comment: yes i do have filled urltitle  ii tried that code earlier then i got the fist error get() got an unexpected keyword argument 'title' but it does the work and do pass in url field

Comment: @Blackranger: just filter with `blog = Blog.objects.filter(urltitle=title)`.

Comment: sorry for your inconvenience that was my bad i fiured it out thankyou

Answer (score 2):

##### template

```html
{% url 'blogs:readblog' title=blogs.urltitle %}
```

here, you pass `title=urltitle`, so you actually pass `urltitle`!

##### views

```py
# your-code | wrong
class ReadBlogs(View):
    def get(self, request, title):
        # ======== HERE, TITLE IS ACTUALLY urltitle! ==================
        readblog = Blog.objects.filter(title=title)
        return render(request,'blogs_read.html', {'readblog':readblog})


# correct
class ReadBlogs(View):
    def get(self, request, title):
        readblog = Blog.objects.filter(urltitle = title)
        return render(request,'blogs_read.html', {'readblog':readblog})
```